# presentOpenInMenuFromRect does not show up

Tags: ios, whatsapp, uidocumentinteraction

`presentOpenInMenuFromRect` doesn't show up even though canOpen returns true. I'm trying to pass a .mov video to Whats App. I'm running iOS 9 on an iPhone 5S. I've tried CGRectZero and also other views, but I never see the popup at all. I'm using a UINavigationController as my self.window.rootViewController

Any thoughts as to what's going on here?

```
self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[self urlOfVideoAsset:video]];
self.documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
self.documentInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.movie";
self.documentInteractionController.annotation = @"Check out my video on www.channel.wtf";

_applicationWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
BOOL canOpen = [self.documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:_applicationWindow.bounds inView:_applicationWindow animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solved it by calling `presentOptionsMenuFromRect` instead.

Comment: Changing to `presentOptionsMenuFromRect` did not work for me unfortunately.